# ServiceStack and SSL (HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: https, servicestack, http-status-code-405

My service works on http, however when i try enabling https on IIS I get the following error:
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.

WebDAV module is disabled.